# Fastest way to restart a .NET web app programmatically

Tags: asp.net, performance, e2e-testing, warm-up, application-warmup

I’m writing some e2e tests for a web application where there is a lot of code I need to interact with that is outside my control. In order to setup my application at the start of each test or group of tests, I intend to use sql scripts to seed the database into a known state and then force the web app to restart so that all internal caches outside my control are all reset.

With that in mind, does anyone know what approach will give me the fastest restart of a web app?

Options I’ve got are:

1. Touch the web.config
2. Create then remove an app_offline.htm file in the root
3. Create some API that can call HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain

Are any of these methods faster than any other? Are are they all effectively the same?

Comment: Can you clarify:  "so that all internal caches outside my control are all reset?" Are you worried about data queries being cached? The GAC does not cache data results so you wouldn't need to worry about restarting the app. Restarting the app is costly 'timewise' make sure you really want to do it.

Comment: More that the 3rd part maintains a caching layer such that seeding the database isn’t enough. Additionally, I can’t be certain everything the 3rd part code is caching so I just want to restart to be  sure.

Comment: not sure what the 3rd part is? Or what it contains? If you believe that it contains cached data and is outside of the application domain then restarting the app will not affect that caching? 
I have a recommendation for you about how to restart the app between test/requests but I want to make sure that restarting the app is in fact what you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use option # 3:

```
System.Web.HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();
```

This method terminates the current application. The application restarts the next time a request is received for it.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpruntime.unloadappdomain?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: But does this restart faster than the others is what I’m asking?

Comment: From a programming perspective and programmatically, that would be faster. Besides you don't have to mess with web.config or use the app_offline.htm.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest, expose an endpoint which will clear/refresh the cache. Can that endpoint from your e/e test.

Comment: Like I said, I’m not in control of all the code and so I can’t clear what isn’t mine.

Answer (score 0):

As per your suggested methods:

1. Touch the web.config
2. Create then remove an app_offline.htm file in the root
3. Create some API that can call HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain

Both **1** and **2** seem a little clunky and require coding a separate API to do programmatically.
3 Seems less clunky but definitely requires coding an API.

As per my comments I am not sure that restarting the app is necessary or will accomplish what you need, as the data being reseeded will not be cached in the `GAC`. If the data is coming from a `Web API` then you might consider restarting that API. The best way to do that is through the `[![IIS AppPool advanced settings][1]][1]`:

You want to make sure you settings are as follows:
Start Mode: OnDemand
*Idle Time-out (Minutes): 0
Idle Time-out Action:    Terminate

All those settings are default except for the time-out minutes, which are 20  by default. By setting it to 0 on the your app or the third part AP the application will Terminate (dumped from the GAC) and will restart upon a new web request.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dani. Re the cached data, I know it’s cached “in memory” so restarting the app just seemed the most surefire way of ensuring everything is cleared. 

Thanks for the suggestion, that’s not one I’d thought of. Not sure if it’s quite what I would need though as the app will make quite a few requests during the e2e tests. Ultimately I need to control when the restart occurs, not just a blanket reset after each request.

Comment: Worth noting: Data query results are cached in DataBase management system (server) and not in the web application. When you reseed your data you will reset the data cached results.